# CSS alignment of a ghost button

Tags: css, button, ghost

I am trying to add a ghost button on a bootstrap carousel here: http://oarvoredo.businesscatalyst.com/

It's the first slide the white button.

```
.a_banner a {
    color:#FFF !important;
    font-size:22px !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 75% !important;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-right:40%;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius:16px;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
}
```

I am not being able to center it properly with `position:absolute;`. How can I make this work?

Comment: What made you use `margin-left: 40%`? What browsers should this support?

Answer (score 0):

Set left to 50% and margin-left to minus half of button width.

```
.a_banner a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -100px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```